# How to call method in view from viewmodel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having view and viewmodel in swiftUi in view i have one function to show alert which need to call when API call get failed. API functionality is written in view model, I am not sure how to call method from view when api gives error in viewmodel.

//View

```
  @State private var showDialogBox = false

  func action(message: String) {
        showDialogBox.toggle()
  }

  var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .afklSpacingL) {
            Text(TranslationKeys.selectPassengerTitle.title)
        }
  }
    .overlay(showDialogBox ? AnyView(DialogBoxTwoButtons(accessibilityID: "dialogboxes", dialogboxType: .warning, dialogboxTitle: "Title", dialogboxBody: "body", dialogboxFirstButtonTitle: "Ok", dialogboxFirstButtonCallback: { action(message: "Ok") }, dialogboxSecondButtonTitle: "Cancel", dialogboxSecondButtonCallback: { action(message: "Cancel") }, isDialogboxFirstButtonClicked: $isDialogboxFirstButtonClicked, isDialogboxSecondButtonClicked: $isDialogboxSecondButtonClicked)
            ) : AnyView(EmptyView()))
```

//Viewmodel

```
extension abcViewModel: Listener {

    func apiCall(error: KitError?, uuid: UUID) {
        if error == nil,
           
        } else {
             //call "action" method in View to show dialog box
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to show an alert, learn about the `.sheet` modifier instead.

Comment: Yeah we have separate module for that..but my question is about how to call method in view from viewmodel..can you plz help me in that

Comment: You should never do that, so no I can’t help you with that. If you learn about sheet you will understand that you instead communicate with the view by setting a property in your view model that the view watches.

Comment: Why not have the alert shown as a result of the change of a variable in the view model. In other words, in `abcViewModel` make an `@Published var showDialogBox`? The view just displays, and the view model contains the logic.

Answer (score 0):

What should a ViewModel be capable of?

> The view model is an abstraction of the view exposing the public
> properties and commands. Instead of the controller of the MVC pattern,
> or the presenter of the MVP pattern, MVVM has a binder, which
> automates communication between the view and its bound properties in
> the view model.

What you should be doing is create a shared Instance of your ViewModel Or you can use a coordinator for that but for your solution shared instance can be used in your view. Just like this

```
class abcViewModel {
   static var shared = abcViewModel()
   func apiCall(error: KitError?, uuid: UUID) {
       if error == nil{
       
       } else {
            //call "action" method in View to show dialog box
       }
   }
```

}

And in your view

```
var viewModel = abcViewModel.shared
```

Now your public methods are available in your view class.

There might be even better options out there. Everyone here is for learning.
Thanks.